# Font size increasing for Outlook 2013 with High DPI

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email, outlook-2013

Good day, I've run into an issue with Outlook 2013 120 DPI, which I just cannot figure out. I'm able to get the layout to be mostly correct, but the font size in my cells just will not stay the size I am specifying, it keeps increasing. My Litmus test is here: https://litmus.com/builder/6250d6d, also contains the code.

Essentially, I need the red cell on the left to be shorter than the image on the right, which it is correct in literally every other environment (though the table structure of this example is normally conditional, I've made it standard for ease of use in determining the issue)

Any suggestions will be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is what Outlook (all versions) does on systems with the 120 dpi setting. I have yet to see any way documented to detect the setting or correct the behavior. You either have to design the email so that this isn't an issue, or not worry about it, which seems to be what most email marketers do at the moment.

Comment: to go along with Michael's answer, see this link for some ways to create your email with Outlook DPI issue in mind: https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/dpi_scaling_in_outlook_2007-2013

Comment: Michael: That's what I was afraid of. For my own templates, the issue isn't major. They don't look AS good in this setting, but it's to small a number of end users for me to actually worry about. Now I just have to hope my clients will be willing to listen when I tell them the issue is not correctable... @Gortonington: I actually did use that guide in making this code, but do you see anything in my code that isn't in line with what that guide teaches?

Comment: try defining width on the second TD (holding the image) and possibly also the image itself. the 120 dpi also scales images, so by leaving it to 'auto' or 100% can change the way it is scaled (especially as Outlook tends to hate percents on images).

Comment: @Gortonington Unfortunately if I define that width on that cell, the cell expands beyond the image, which I have been unable to solve as of yet.